# error messages::ext4-fs error(device dm-0) after write-error on swap device

Tags: kernel, swap, panic

recently, i moved fedora29 into the desktop harddrive from external hard drive
(Miraculously, i installed fedora29 on external hard drive anyway ^^:)

as installed as soon, it was too slow. i added up second swap partition on the secondary hard disk(/dev/sda1:4TB)

after that, my computer was always busy with hdd led on(hdd is too busy to work).
then i removed the second swap partition, the secondary disk from the `/etc/fstab`. 
Since then, my computer became unstable..like write-error , kernel panic...etc

```
EXT4-fs error(device dm-0):ext4_find_entry:1439: inode #1966722: comm systemd:reading directory lblock 0
EXT4-fs error(device dm-0):ext4_journal-check_start: Detected aborted journal
EXT4-fs(dm-0):Remounting filesytem read-only
cpu3: Core Temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled(total events:1)
```

Because of removed the secondary disk,there is no `dm-0`(maybe mounted disk name with `/etc/fstab`)
How could i fix the problem???

`/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root / ext4 defaults 1 1 UUID=9b493611-0fb7-491b-9fc0-ae42f5a54a3f /boot ext4 defaults 1 2 
/dev/mapper/fedora-home /home ext4 defaults 1 2 
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap swap swap defaults 0 0
```

`blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="5fedba61-5bf3-4c50-9818-bc63b771306a" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="84d63caf-ab6d-4350-af92-39e87755a96d" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="9b493611-0fb7-491b-9fc0-ae42f5a54a3f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9b543e06-01" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="qnCBLA-tzkn-Lt0E-m9ed-4Ujj-W1A2-OAtoFG" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="9b543e06-02" 
/dev/mapper/fedora-root: UUID="5a09dd9f-03c5-474f-8e13-08aa5cde26a4" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap: UUID="28a3e920-5418-4799-9e18-5e501b838447" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/fedora-home: UUID="b3c099eb-83e1-4328-98bf-e8f46c59e35f" TYPE="ext4".
```

`df -h`

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
devtmpfs 2.0G 0 2.0G 0% /dev 
tmpfs 2.0G 0 2.0G 0% /dev/shm 
tmpfs 2.0G 1.1M 2.0G 1% /run 
tmpfs 2.0G 0 2.0G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
/dev/mapper/fedora-root 49G 19G 29G 39% / 
tmpfs 2.0G 4.0K 2.0G 1% /tmp 
/dev/sdb1 1008M 203M 737M 22% /boot 
/dev/mapper/fedora-home 52G 9.0G 41G 19% /home 
tmpfs 395M 0 395M 0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: Please share your `cat /etc/fstab` and the output of `blkid` and `df -h`. Also, looks like you have CPU Temp issues, I lost a CPU Core last time I saw a message like that. Did you build this computer yourself or have it custom built by a friend/local business etc?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers my computer is customed built by local bizz..--;

Comment: Yeah I'd look into reseating your CPU then with good diamond paste

Comment: It hurts my eyes reading everything on one line, can you fix the formatting?

Comment: I fixed your formatting as best I could but the `df -h` still looks horrible, I would literally copy and paste the code from the terminal and enclose in code brackets, that way we might notice something you missed.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers i found that the bottom part of Cpu cooler fan has broken when reseating Cpu. i ordered a used cooler on-line market. i am going to exchage the cooler today...hmm

Comment: Who knows, maybe that will fix your other issues, but I'm not sure if its hardware or software. Regardless, I'm glad your fixing that! Easier to fix software then hardware. CPU Heat issues is kinda like water damage on a cell phone, it can do wonky things.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers finally succeded in reseating CPU. Until now, this computer Works well!! thanks to Ur Advice.

Comment: @JungsuepYoon If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the following line 
`cpu3: Core Temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled(total events:1)`

and not to long back I lost a CPU when ignoring similar messages. I suspect your CPU might need reseating and that this may fix the problem. Hot CPU can cause all sorts of issues. Hope that fixes it!

Comment: After changing the cpu to the present, my computer is very stable. Maybe the trouble has been the CPU problem..

Comment: If you feel the answer solved your problem, go ahead and vote/accept please. Welcome to Unix.Linux SE! You may want to wait a few days to confirm the issue is fixed, but users appreciate it when you vote/accept answers they put time/effort into.